# Continuity of $F(x,y)=|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x,y)=|x-y|$. Prove using $\epsilon-\delta$ that $F(x,y)$ is continuous.

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. We have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for any $(x,y)$ with $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2<\delta^2$ we have $|F(x,y)-F(x_0, y_0)|<\epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given then taking $\delta=\epsilon/2$ we get:
$$|F(x,y)-F(x_0, y_0)|=||x-y|-|x_0-y_0||\leqslant |x-y-x_0+y_0|=|(x-x_0)-(y-y_0)|\leqslant $$ $$\leqslant |x-x_0|+|y-y_0|<2\delta=\epsilon.$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: How do you justify the first inequality? I recommend writing down a justification for each step.

Comment: @flawr, $||a|-|b||\leqslant |a-b|$. Right?

Comment: your proof is correct

Comment: @A.Ward.2016 That is what I'm asking you to justify.

Comment: Your proof is fine and answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is kind of being entangled by details, instead of catching  structure of the problem in a smart way. That kind of proof usually looks  complicated. Here is one much more clear and logical:

Let $g(x,y)=x-y$, then $F(x,y)=|g(x,y)|$.

- Step 1. Prove g(x,y) is continuous.  It is very easy.
- Step 2. Prove $|\cdot|$ is continuous.  It is very easy.
- Step 3. Composition of continuous functions is still continuous.